# How can I add additional lighting fixtures to an existing 3-way circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a light on a pair of 3 way switches.  I want to add 5 recessed cans to that circuit.  It is currently set up with power at the light fixture and 14/3 wires ran from the fixture to both switches. Can I tie the other fixtures into this setup using 14/2 and running my wires parallel?  If not, what would be a suggested way of doing it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  You'll connect the wires feeding to the next fixture, to the wires that feed the current light fixture.

Basically, you'll start with this...

[image: basic 3-way wiring]

Then you'll add the additional lights like this...

[image: Additional light fixtures]

***NOTES:***

- *I've excluded the grounding conductors to simplify the diagram, make sure you properly ground all the fixtures.*
- *The black wire coming from the "3-way wiring" bubble, might actually be white, red, or some other color.*